# ADB root acces not working

Tags: adb, root-access

I have installed a Custom Rome on my Nexus 5x. In the developer options, I can activate USB debugging, but I can not give ADB any root rights.

Is there a possibility to assign ADB root rights?

I have tried that and received the message "not running as root"

Heres a Picture from my CMD:
[image]

With another rom it has already worked.

[This](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-5x/development/rom-pure-nexus-layers-fi-wifi-calling-t3244601) is the rom i use.

Comment: Have you tried setting SELinux to "permissive" in adb shell?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: run `adb shell` in the shell console type`'setenforce 0` . Then retry earlier commands.

Comment: SELinux-Status has changed. I still get the message "not running as root".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60382/discussion-between-xavier-fakerat-and-clemse).

Comment: I have a feeling that your kernel is running adbd in secure mode. Could you tell us the output of `adb shell getprop ro.secure`?

Comment: I'm not at the PC, so I tried it with a terminal emulator. The output it was: 1

Comment: Are you sure you have root? The description of the ROM doesn't say it's rooted, and someone else on the forum page you linked gives instructions for installing a selection of `su` implementations.

Comment: I have flashed supersu. Ich dont have Problems with other root apps.